# BaseClient.handshake was never awaited rich presence

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make an *on_ready* event that asks me if I want rich presence on my client and typing "n" or "no" works but typing "y" or "yes" give me the error. I am not sure if there is anything I need to await since I am fairly new to rich presence.

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\selma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\selma\OneDrive\Desktop\Phoenix Bot\main.py", line 1651, in on_ready
    await rpc.connect()
  File "C:\Users\selma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypresence\presence.py", line 43, 
in connect
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.handshake())
  File "C:\Users\selma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 618, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "C:\Users\selma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 578, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
C:\Users\selma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:350: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseClient.handshake' was never awaited
  pass
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user.name} is ready.") 
    print(f"Started at: {datetime.datetime.utcnow()}")
    print(f"Guilds: {len(client.guilds)}")
    print("Do you want Rich Presence?(y/n)")
    e = input("")
    if e.lower() == "y":
      rpc = Presence("804897816434180096")
      await rpc.connect()
      await rpc.update(
        details="Invite and Vote Below",
        large_image="phoenix",
        large_text="Invite Phoenix Bot",
        buttons = [
          {"label": "Invite Phoenix Bot", "url": "https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=804897816434180096&scope=bot%20applications.commands&permissions=8" }, {"label": "Vote For Phoenix Bot", "url": "https://top.gg/bot/804897816434180096/vote" }
        ]
      )
      
    elif e.lower() == "yes":
      rpc = Presence("804897816434180096")
      await rpc.connect()
      await rpc.update(
        details="Invite and Vote Below",
        large_image="phoenix",
        large_text="Invite Phoenix Bot",
        buttons = [
          {"label": "Invite Phoenix Bot", "url": "https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=804897816434180096&scope=bot%20applications.commands&permissions=8" }, {"label": "Vote For Phoenix Bot", "url": "https://top.gg/bot/804897816434180096/vote" }
        ]
      )
    
    elif e.lower() == "n":
      return print("Rich Presence is off")
    elif e.lower() == "no":
      return print("Rich Presence is off")
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the RPC module you're using?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pypresence/

Comment: Do not duplicate code (here in "y&yes branches", same for "n&no").

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any way to test, but you could try specifying the `loop` parameter on the call to `Presence()`. Like this:

```py
rpc = Presence("804897816434180096", loop=client.loop)
```

Also, please use an `or` statement instead of duplicating code.

Instead of:

```
    elif e.lower() == "n":
      return print("Rich Presence is off")
    elif e.lower() == "no":
      return print("Rich Presence is off")
```

Do this:

```
    elif e.lower() == "n" or e.lower() == "no":
       return print("Rich Presence is off")
```

Comment: When I tried to do that, It gave me the same error. Is there something else I need to add?

Comment: instead of `loop=client.loop`, try `loop=asyncio.new_event_loop()`

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the docs solved it, `Presence().connect()` is not a coroutine, i.e not to be awaited.

```py
rpc = Presence("804897816434180096")
rpc.connect()
rpc.update(**kwargs)
```

[pypresence quickstart](https://qwertyquerty.github.io/pypresence/html/info/quickstart.html#quickstart)

Comment: If you look at the error, this is not the problem. Awaiting a non-awaitable would give a different error.

Comment: I tried that but got the same error, I made a new way.